# Find and set as variable specific text in CMD

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, copy, find

I am creating a batch script, and I need a little help. I am trying to make the batch  automatically identify the iPhone version, by just looking at the IPSW, so for example: iPhone5,2_9.2.1_11D25_Restore.ipsw, i want to set "5,2" as a variable, but I need to find it first.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will it always be in the same place in the string? If not, how will you know when you found it?

Comment: Yes, it is always in the same place. iPhone5,2_9.1, iPhone3,1_7.1.2 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been nice to know that these were file names and not text in a document; I had no idea what an IPSW was until this question.

This assumes you have multiple IPSW files in the same directory as the script.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A in ('dir /b *.ipsw') do (
    set iDevice=%%A
    set iVersion=%%B

    REM Take the last character before the comma and the first character after the comma
    set "device_version=!iDevice:~-1!,!iVersion:~0,1!"

    echo !device_version!
)
```

Comment: Hey, this fixed it, but i am having some other issues. Can we chat somewhere?

Comment: @user6025782 - You don't have enough rep to use the site's chat feature, but you can email me at 8a6b1987@opayq.com I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "IPSW=iPhone5,2_9.2.1_11D25_Restore.ipsw"
FOR /f "delims=_" %%a IN ("%IPSW%") DO SET "iphoneversion=%%a"

IF "%iphoneversion:~0,6%"=="iPhone" (SET "iphoneversion=%iphoneversion:~6%") ELSE (SET iphoneversion=?)

ECHO iphoneversion=%iphoneversion%

GOTO :EOF
```

Assuming you have `IPSW` set to the string you require (I used your supplied string to test) then the above routine will first assign the portion of `IPSW` up to but not including the first `_` to `%%a` and thence to `iphoneversion`.

If the first 6 characters are exactly `iPhone` then thos first 6 are removed, otherwise the value is set to `?`

Comment: Basically, i want to identify the version from the ipsw itself, and the version is written right after iPhone, so: iPhone5,2, iPhone4,1...